# Angular Material causing Unhandled Promise rejection: Failed to load

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

I am getting unhandled and live server not responding issue in angular 4. i am using angular material and app just broke due to mdc.select.min.css cannout be found in @material>select. the following issue started out of blue just by restarting the computer. i can see in the files in required folder. but still getting the error.tried generating new project and install all the packages again but  no luck.

here is the error

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
:4200/node_modules//dist/mdc.select.min.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

polyfills.bundle.js:3057 Unhandled Promise rejection: Failed to load ../../../../../node_modules//dist/mdc.select.min.css ; Zone: ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Failed to load ../../../../../node_modules//dist/mdc.select.min.css undefined

api.onUnhandledError @ polyfills.bundle.js:3057
polyfills.bundle.js:3059 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Failed to load ../../../../../node_modules//dist/mdc.select.min.css


at resolvePromise (polyfills.bundle.js:3184)
at resolvePromise (polyfills.bundle.js:3155)
at polyfills.bundle.js:3232
at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (polyfills.bundle.js:2838)
at Zone.webpackJsonp.../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (polyfills.bundle.js:2605)
at drainMicroTaskQueue (polyfills.bundle.js:2998)
at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (polyfills.bundle.js:2904)
api.onUnhandledError @ polyfills.bundle.js:3059
](url)
```

---

angular-cli.json

---

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "edrop"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
       "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],

      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Is your project generated with **angular-cli**, if yes show us the content of **angular-cli.json**

Comment: @codtex i have updated the the angular-cli.json content in original question, please review. thanks

Comment: `mdc.select.min.css` sounds like material1. Are you trying to use material1 with Angular4?

Comment: Well I think that this file **mdc.select.min.css** is not found on the right place, you can try putting it in **angular-cli.json -> styles -> '../node_modules/@material/select/dist/mdc.select.min.css'** but I suggest you to use https://material.angular.io/ instead of https://material.io/components/

Comment: using material 2. @codtex. tried but no difference.

Comment: @TayyabRahman can you also show your package.json?